# (SQL) How to apply case statement with percentile to calculate median on a group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using case statement to calculate statistics on certain criteria like following

```
avg(case when det.detection_time >0 then det.blocked_time end) 

and

sum(case when det.detection_time  =0 then 1 else 0 end)
```

**How should I apply case statement to get median.**.

Currently I am getting median like following:

```
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER by det.blocked_time)
```

How should I add condition "case when det.detection_time >0"  to the PERCENTILE_CONT block to get median for group where det.detection_time >0

Comment: show some sample data and the expected output and explain why your approach doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.  My approach is working.  I am getting median.  But I want to get median case when det.detection_time >0.  Therefore I need to apply something like PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP( case when det.detection_time >0 ORDER by det.blocked_time end).  I am not sure how to add this information.

Comment: can you post the full query and show us some sample data and the expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [FILTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) to achieve it and make your SQL cleaner:

```
SELECT
    avg(det.blocked_time) FILTER (WHERE det.detection_time > 0),
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE det.detection_time = 0),
    percentile_cont(0.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER by det.blocked_time) FILTER (WHERE det.detection_time > 0)
FROM 
    my_table det;
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is the following:

```
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN det.detection_time >0 THEN det.blocked_time ELSE NULL END) AS [COLUMN NAME]
```

Since PERCENTILE_CONT is an aggregate fxn like AVG you will need to groupby